# MySQL SELECT, JOIN TABLES AND GROUP/COUNT COMMA SEPARATED VALUES

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, count

I have the following two tables:

```
**Table: appointments**
--------------------------
id | user_id | date
--------------------------
1  |    18    | 23/02/2018
2  |    24    | 24/02/2018
3  |    18    | 24/02/2018
--------------------------


**Table: appointments_services**
--------------------------------
id | appointment_id | service_id
--------------------------------
1  |        1       | 23,26
2  |        2       | 12,23
3  |        3       | 23,45,12
--------------------------------
```

I would like to have the following reports:

1) Based on a date period I will enter, to group the services and show me a total/count
2) On the same date period to show me how many total/count services a `user_id` has made

If the above two reports need to be in a different SQL I do not mind.

**This is what I have done so far:**

```
SELECT * FROM appointments_services s
JOIN appointments a ON s.appointment_id = a.id

WHERE STR_TO_DATE(a.date, '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01/03/2018', '%d/%m/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('05/03/2018', '%d/%m/%Y')
```

I got stuck now because the `service_id` is in comma separated values and I do not know how to split them and group/count them.

Comment: Normalise your schema.

Comment: This is what the current database is even if i change it from now on we still need the reports from how it used to be so i am looking for a better solution for my problem

Answer (score 0):

A normalised environment might read as follows:

```
**Table: appointments_services**

appointment_id | service_id
---------------+----------------
             1 |         23
             1 |         26
             2 |         12
             2 |         23
             3 |         23
             3 |         45
             3 |         12
```

From here, the problem is trivial.